# Почему не находит окно по точному названию? c++ WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi

Используя Spy++ пытаюсь найти окно браузера "Без имени – Яндекс.Браузер", но FindWindow его не находит.

```
BYTE R, G;
HWND Handle = FindWindow(NULL, _T("Без имени — Яндекс.Браузер"));

if (Handle != NULL) {
    std::cout << "Window IS found!\n";
    POINT cursorPos;
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetCursorPos(&cursorPos))
        {
            if (ScreenToClient(Handle, &cursorPos)) {
                std::cout << "{ " << cursorPos.x << " , " << cursorPos.y << " }" << std::endl;
                Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "Window is NOT found!\n";
}
```

Comment: Окна на английском находит?

Comment: Он находит любое окно, кроме окна браузера. И всякие калькуляторы, что угодно, но вот найти окно со вкладкой - нет.

Comment: Что такое окно со вкладкой? Другие браузеры находит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую вам почитать документацию по  [FindWindow](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Window/fn_findwindow.htm)

Тут небольшая вырезка из неё.

Функция `FindWindow` извлекает дескриптор окна верхнего уровня, имя класса и имя окна которого соответствуют заданным строкам. Эта функция не ищет дочерние окна. Эта функция не выполняет регистрозависимый поиск.

Чтобы найти дочерние окна, начинающиеся с заданного дочернего окна, используют функцию `FindWindowEx`

**Возвращаемые значения**

Если функция завершилась успешно, возвращаемое значение - дескриптор окна, которое имеет заданное имя класса и имя окна.

Если функция завершается ошибкой, возвращаемое значение - ПУСТО (NULL). Чтобы получить дополнительные данные об ошибках, вызовите функцию `GetLastError`.

**Вывод**.

Так как это браузер то я предполагаю что это окно не верхнего уровня, и посмотреть что вернет `GetLastError`

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по названию окна довольно не стабилен, возможно стоит задуматься над поиском по названию процесса или же получить окно под курсором [WindowFromPoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint?redirectedfrom=MSDN)